# What other verbs could I use to say that the fragrance from one person "gets" onto another person?

Tags: verbs, synonyms

Another person can smell the same with the one that comes in close contact.

Answer (score 3):

- The fragrance from one person **transfers** onto another person.

From a scientific article [Analysis of Transferred Fragrance and its Forensic 
Implications]:

> Studies were carried on the dynamics of perfume **transfer** between
>   fabrics.

This article studied the **transference** of fragrances ( perfumes, aftershave and cologne ) between a victim and assaulter.